# Understanding components and props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having problems figuring out how to use components and props.

More specifically, I'm trying to update the data in a component and have it change the component. I have an array of objects which the component template iterates through. I would like to change that array and have the change reflected in the component.

Here's my toy example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input id="opp-list-input" v-model="opportunityListVals" type="hidden">
        <br>
        <opportunitylist v-bind:opp-list="opportunityListVals"></opportunitylist>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                opportunityListVals: [{name: 'First Opportunity'},{name: 'Second Opportunity'}]
            },
            components: {
                opportunitylist: {
                    props: ['oppList'],
                    template: '<ul>'
+ '<li v-for="opp in oppList">'
+ '{{opp.name}}'
+ '</li>'
+ '</ul>'
                }
            }
        });
        $('#opp-list-input').val([{name: 'Third Opportunity'}]);
        $("#opp-list-input").change();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to finally display just the single "Third Opportunity" line even though it was initialized with two different values.

When I run this it gives me duplicate value warnings and displays a number of empty bullets.  I assume that means that it's not handling the array the way I expect.

Am I on the right track in terms of props and components?

Is there a better way for me to handle that array of objects.  It seems odd sending it through an input element, but every example I saw did it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your components.  Rather than use v-bind, you just need to use `:oppList="opportunityListVals"` to pass that array from parent to child.  When the parent array updates, the child component will automatically update as well.

You also need to use `Vue.extend()` to create a child component, not just send in the object.

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <opportunitylist :oppList="opportunityListVals"></opportunitylist>
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            opportunityListVals: [{name: 'First Opportunity'},{name: 'Second Opportunity'}]
        },
        components: {
            opportunitylist: Vue.extend({
                props: ['oppList'],
                template: '<ul>'
                    + '<li v-for="opp in oppList">'
                    + '{{opp.name}}'
                    + '</li>'
                    + '</ul>'
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

I don't really understand what you were doing with that input and the third value, so you'll have to clarify that before I can provide input there.